# floattext of a TextField overlaps with initial text content instead of floating up

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I am using the `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField` class with a floattext, here is the snippet from FXML:

```
<TextField fx:id="email" floatText="E-Mail" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="357.0">
           <opaqueInsets>
              <Insets />
           </opaqueInsets>
        </TextField>
```

When the field is initially empty, everything works as expected: The `floattext` "E-Mail" floats up as soon as I click on the `TextField`. However, when I load already existing data into the `TextFiled`:

```
baseView.showingProperty().addListener((_obs, _oldValue, _newValue) -> {
        if (_newValue) {
            final String _email ="myemail";
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    email.setText(_email);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

then the float text stays inside the edit area, overlapping with the text `"myemail"` already set. How can I make the float text initially appear already floated up, a state as if I had entered the text now?

This may not be a bug, but rather a misunderstanding from my side about how to use this feature.

Comment: Which Charm version are you using?

Comment: Here is the charm - dependency copied from the build.gradle:   dependencies {/com/gluonhq/charm/
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.0'
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3' ......

Comment: Can you check with charm 4.3.7? I'm afraid there has been a regression, as this issue was already fixed before.